# AnyLogic: a single traffic lane for public transport

Tags: anylogic

My objective is to restrict any means of transport (except for public transport) from moving on a particular traffic lane. Thus, I am intended to allow a single lane for public transport. Is it possible to create it only with the interface elements? Also, I would appreciate it if some references are provided because I didn't find any in "AnyLogic Help".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible directly.

You will have to create 2 parallel roads. You can make them look like 1 road with 2 lanes but it must be 2 roads. Then, send public transport via 1 of these 2 roads.

Obviously, you need to create entry/exit points so public transport can re-join normal traffic.